# Where to look for documentation regarding iPhone telephone app

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm new to the iPhone sdk and I'd like to know what kinds of functionality and documentation exist for the iPhone telephone app. Ie how can you make calls/get any information about calls for your personal iPhone app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API in the current iOS SDK to retrieve call history or make calls from within your app. There is an [Address Book API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) (which will let you retrieve all the details for contacts in the iPhone Address Book, including phone numbers, etc.) but I don't think this is what you want. If you wanted to launch the Phone app and initiate a phone call from your app, you could do the following:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"8885555";
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString]];
```

Note that this will close your app and open the Phone app.

Comment: Interesting, so there's no way to actually get any information from another app without closing yours?

Comment: Not at the moment. I think restricting access to call history, etc. is more of a security issue so I can see why Apple wouldn't allow 3rd party apps to do that.